# Eclipse - how to start remote debugging without automatically rebuilding

Tags: eclipse, debugging, build

[using Eclipse 3.6 and Preferances -> Workspace -> build automatically is disabled]

I have a project setup that includes a number of scripted steps for generating autogen code (jaxb, etc).  It also automatically produces and deploys (does not start) my jars to a remote server.  Unfortunatly this whole process can take upwards of 2 minutes.

Recently I've been remotely debugging one project by starting it on the remote server with a manual script that enables remote debugging then attaching to the remote debugging session with eclipse.  My problem is that even if I have not made any source changes, eclipse performs a rebuild when I start the remote debugging session.  This is really annoying.  Does anyone know how to start Eclipse's remote debugging without automatically performing a rebuild?

Answer (score 31):

You probably have figured this out, but for sake of future reference, to accomplish this:

Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching. Uncheck build(if required) before launching.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

- On "Project" menu, uncheck the "Build Automatically"

The down side is that now you'll have to invoke "Build" manually each time you need.

Comment: This doesn't fix the OP's question